# Is there a way to get all the items from a list that have a specific property

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a list of Containers and was wondering how to return a list with all the containers that are Valuable.

This is my code so far:

ContainerType.cs:

```
    public enum ContainerType
    {
        Normal,
        Cooled,
        Valuable
    }
```

Container.cs:

```
        public ContainerType Type;
        public int Weight { set; get; }

        public Container(ContainerType type, int weight)
        {
            Weight = weight;
            Type = type;
        }
```

Row.cs:

```
        public List<Container> GetValuable(List<Container> List)
        {
            return List.OfType<ContainerType.Valuable>();              
        }
```

The method in row gives these 2 errors:

```
CS0426  The type name 'Valuable' does not exist in the type 'ContainerType'

CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Containervervoer.Models.ContainerType.Valuable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Containervervoer.Models.Container>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: You may be confused as to how [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) works or what it does.  A simple `Where` should work

Comment: you're right, with samyap's answer it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LINQ `Where` function to achieve this.

```
public List<Container> GetValuable(List<Container> list)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.ContainerType == ContainerType.Valuable).ToList();              
}
```

The `ToList()` should fix your casting issue.

Comment: no problem, read this article to get more info on how `Where` works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1